# RStudio on Windows not using XeLaTeX

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, pdflatex, xelatex

I'm using **RStudio** 0.99.896 on Windows 10.

I am trying to use **knitr** to convert a **RMarkdown** file to PDF using the **XeLaTex** engine.

I have set the Global Options *and* the Project Options in RStudio to build with XeLaTex

You can see that I have selected XeLaTeX in the global options (see pic)
[image]

and I have also selected it in the project options (see pic)
[image]

Here is a minimal reproducible example of a markdown file that fails when I call knitr:

````
---
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{fontspec}
output:
    pdf_document
---


```{r}
data(mtcars)
```
````

When I call **Knit PDF** on the file above, I get the following output:

> "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   sample1.utf8.md --to latex --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures
>   --output sample1.pdf --template "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.14.tex"
>   --highlight-style tango **--latex-engine pdflatex** --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"  output file:
>   sample1.knit.md
>
> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ! ! Fatal fontspec
>   error: "cannot-use-pdftex" !  ! The fontspec package requires either
>   XeTeX or LuaTeX to function. !  ! You must change your typesetting
>   engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" ! instead of plain "latex" or
>   "pdflatex".

You can see in the bold part of the output shown above that RStudio is still calling **pdflatex** instead of **xelatex**.

I'm not sure why that is. Any thoughts on a setting that I have missed?

Comment: As stated in the Rstudio preferences, the settings are for *Rnw* files ; here, you are working with *Rmarkdown*. You need to add the `latex_engine: xelatex` setting in the YAML front matter in every document.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too.

Try this:

```
output:
   pdf_document:
     latex_engine: xelatex
```

In addition to everything else you did. This fixed it for me!